# Usage rule for verbs being used in singular and plural form after pronouns

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, singular-vs-plural

If there is singular pronoun like ***it,   she/he*** ; the verb succeeding the pronoun should be singular form or plural. Is there any sentence construction rule?

- > It gives you
- > It give you

Also with  pronoun like ***they, that*** ; how it should be used

- > They give you.
- > They gives you

Answer (score 1):

The 'rule' is exactly the same with a pronoun as with a noun. So you would write "The son gives you" and not "The son give you". Similarly "the children give you" and not "the children gives you".

Comment: So, if I am speaking to 2 people, I should say "You give me" and if I am speaking to 1 person I should say "You give**s** me"?

Comment: Only in third person singular is an 's' added to the end of the verb. So 'you' will always 'give' me, regardless of whether 'you' is singular or plural. 'He gives me' but 'they give me'.

Comment: So the rule is different for pronouns and nouns?

Comment: @Araucaria: the rules are the same: a pronoun can be considered to be the same as a noun. That's the first sentence in my answer.